# Make a bubble level with Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gyroscope

I'm starting with Unity 3D and I want to make a simple game where you move a marble through a maze by tilting the device.

For that I need to know in what the direction the phone is tilted (where to move the ball) and how much (how fast to move it). This bubble level from iOS7 does something similar, the number rotates to show the direction you are tilting the device and the value represents how much the phone is tilted:

[image]

I've been experimenting with Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles but I'm not sure how to turn it into the values I need, also I'm not sure if gyro.attitude is the best solution to get responsive controls.

How can I get the direction and tilt of the device?

Unity3D documentation has a solution using Input.accelaration however I'm not sure whether it's as reliable as Input.gyro.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input-acceleration.html

This is what I'm trying now:

```
private Gyroscope gyro;

void Start () {
    gyro = Input.gyro; // Store the reference for Gyroscope sensor 
    gyro.enabled = true; //Enable the Gyroscope sensor
}

void Update () { 
    // Gyroscope
    Vector3 vec = gyro.attitude * Vector3.forward;
    print (vec);

    // Option 2
    print(Input.accelaration);
}
```

Comment: It would be easier for would-be helpers if you post what you have for us to critique

Comment: I just added some info. I haven't made much progress though. Also I'm not sure if I should be using Input.gyro.attitude.eulerAngles, I cannot make sense of them.

Comment: eulerAngles will be pretty unreliable if any of the rotations passes 90 degrees, partiuclarly the first one.  

You might find this helpful: http://invensense.com/mems/gyro/documents/whitepapers/Unity3D%20Tutorial%201.pdf

Comment: Have a Look At This Tutorial : http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-a-ball

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this (in this case, taking the XZ plane projection of the quaternion = change the Vector3 in the second line to pick the plane you want);

```
    // where q is the Quaternion from the gyro

    Matrix4x4 quatMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, q, Vector3.one);
    Matrix4x4 scaleMatrix = Matrix4x4.TRS(Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity, new Vector3(1, 0, 1));
    Matrix4x4 scaled_matrix  = scaleMatrix * quatMatrix;
    OutVector = scaled_matrix.MultiplyVector(Vector3.forward).normalized;
```

That should give you a 3-d vector that has only X and Z components, easy to turn into a 2-d vector.

Comment: hi @theodox I added a bounty. I tried your code, please take a look at the edited question. I don't think it's giving me the right results tough. I'm going to test it a bit to see if I can understand what's exactly the problem.

Comment: I think the component Z is ok. However the other two seem to be affected by the compass, if I turn around keeping the phone with the same tilt both components change.

Comment: could it be this produces the same results: http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/22883/can-i-get-a-normalised-vector3-from-a-quaternion.html (still affected by the compass though)

Comment: I am not sure that the XZ plane is the one you want, I picked it at random to illustrate how you go from a quat to a 2-d vector.  Or, you could use the trick from the article to change the basis orientation of the the gyro first.

Comment: Input.acceleration actually has all the info I need. But for what I understood from the whitepaper I should use Input.gyro.attitude. Am I wrong? If that is so, what I need is basically to duplicate the results from Input.acceleration with it

Comment: acceleration is only going to tell you how fast the attitude is _changing_, but attitude is where it is _right now_.

Comment: I though the same thing, however I've been printing it and if I keep the device flat with the screen looking up print(Input.acceleration) gives me (0.0, 0.0, -1.0), if I place it vertical on the table (portrait) it says (1.0, 0.0, 0.0). Also I mapped an object's rotation match Input.acceleration.x and Input.acceleration.y and it works exactly as the phone bubble level. How come this happen? Also I found a couple of people building similar games using Input.acceleration http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/397938/physicsgravity-with-tilt-game.html

Comment: Those numbers are because of gravity.  This might help with the axes and figuring out which scale to use on your values:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZWNXsjIvrE

Comment: I could build the functionality with the accelerometer, it's very similar to what the video shows but instead of mapping the accelerometer to an object it's mapped to Physics2D.gravity. Is this the correct solution or should I have used Input.gyro? how is the accelerometer measuring acceleration shouldn't it show (0,0,0) when I keep my device still (no acceleration is happening)?

Comment: That's gravity, isn't it?  Check out the exampkle values here:
http://www.lucedigitale.com/blog/unity-3d-game-engine-android-accelerometer-raw-data-translate-and-object/

Comment: I used Input.gravity was that what you were suggesting? It gave me the same values than Input.acceleration but it wasn't affected sudden accelerations. Anyway thanks for your help. Later I'll add the details of the implementation to your answer.